# Conteúdo da pagina em um sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

Eu estou me aventurando em frontend, estou com dificuldade como eu coloco o conteudo de uma pagina em um sidebar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

exemplo: se eu clicar em 'perfil' apareça o conteúdo do perfil do lado
se clicar em 'voo' o conteúdo do voo parece do lado.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">
            <table>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td><img src="{{ user.avatar(160) }}"></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr><td><h1>Olá {{ user.username }}</h1></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Perfil</a>
          <a href="teste.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Voos</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Check-in</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Pilotos</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Eventos</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Financeiro</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

      <!-- Page Content -->
              <div class="container-fluid">
          <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
          <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
          <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
      $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
      });
    </script>

  </body>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Você se refere a esse recurso: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQbSA.jpg ?

Comment: não, estou falando conteúdo 'texto' quando clico em algum menu no sidebar e não submenu.

Comment: Você diz o conteúdo onde está escrito "Barra Lateral" ? Se não teria como printar e marcar na imagem ?

Comment: Quero que quando clicar no menu lateral (perfil, voo, check-in, eventos )apareça informações (conteudo) do lado(direito).

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, você pode usar ajax para que o div (conteudo) seja recarregado diretamente na pagina, sem carregar.

e.g:

```
$( "#div-to-be-reloaded" ).load( "ajax/complete-response.html" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que seu perfil apareça e seja direcionado quando selecionado no sidebar, uma das opções, é utilizar o atributo href redirecionando a um id. Nesta situação, imagine cada section com seu id específico, por exemplo, "perfil".

Agora, sequencie este, no seu sidebar.

Exemplo:

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#perfil" class="nav-link scrollto active"><i class="bx bx-user"></i><span>Perfil</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Ponto importante:** É uma boa prática prescrever o navbar no header.

Espero ter auxiliado. Fico a disposição para esclarecer maiores dúvidas.